# How to click "Login" button by navigating to webpage from Internet Explorer object?

Tags: vb.net

I'm navigating to a webpage using:

```
Dim IE As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate("http://www.mypage.com")
IE.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("Value", "myusername")
IE.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", "mypassword")

'I can't get the submit button to work here.

'the button is coded in html like this:
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" onclick="return checkCookies();" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
```

I'm not able to click that button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1-What have you tried that has failed so far?    2-Is this code snippet supposed to by a hypothetical example? Because google.com doesn't have a sign in page, and google's actual sign-in page's element id's for the username and password are Email/Passwd, not login/password...

Comment: @soohoonigan this is an example webpage........ DUH! *I've changed the webpage.

Comment: well who knows, I've had to sign in to google with a cefsharp project before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim btns
Set btns = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("btn btn-default pull-right")
For Each btn In btns
    If Button.InnerHTML.Contains("Login") Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm not using webbrowser.